# PHP - Upload 6 Images (MAX 1mb per file)

Tags: php, file, forms, upload, timestamp

I was wondering what the best way to send 6 'file' inputs to a php page would be... and how to process them, i used this website to understand uploading one file

[PHP Tutorial - File Uplaod](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

Also, i want to name each of the 6 images with a time stamp for example below...

```
00000000
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
00000005
```

Basically i just want to +1 to the time stamp, as well i will be uploading the 6 files at once.. so likely the time-stamps will be the same...

This file input will be implemented into a database.. i am planning on storing the image file name in the database then linking to that file in the uploads folder :)

Could anyone link me to a great tutorial on multiple file uploads, or give me some sample code :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are these time stamps?  00000000
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
00000005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can grab the name using the post variable. On the tutorial you linked to, try using $_POST['uploadedfile'] to get the name of the file.

But here is an example of how I handle file uploads where "pageImage" is the name of the file upload field and $filePath is the file upload destination:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES[pageImage]['tmp_name'])){
    $filename=time().".jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[pageImage]['tmp_name'],$filePath.$filename);
    chmod($filePath.$filename,0775);
}
```

hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple file uploads work the same way as any single file uploads, which work the same way as any other form component. You simply need to specify an `<input type='file' name='whatever'>` for each file you want to have uploaded.

Regarding the naming bit, just set the name as you would any other form component:

```
<input type="file" name="000">
<input type="file" name="001">
...
<input type="file" name="005">
```

You can then access it using the `$_FILES` superglobal array.

While we're on the subject, [this page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html) provides a very good, detailed overview of how to manage file uploads via HTML forms.

Comment: Hi
Thanks!
Although, i kind of understood that - but your answer isn't really a answering what i am saying.... i want to know how to interpret those 6 posted inputs - then name them with a timestamp +1 from the date() function in php... i am looking more for the PHP than the html...

Comment: Well, the `date()` function in php is really well documented on the php website (http://www.php.net/date). All you would do to name them is:
<pre>
$name = date(whatever you choose, likely 'YmdHi');
$n = (1,2,3,4,5);
$filename = array();
for($n as $suffix)
{
   $filename[] = $date.$suffix;
}
</pre>
There you go; an array with your file names in them.